# C# - Webbrowser not loading pages to the end

Tags: javascript, c#, getelementbyid, awesomium, invokescript

I have a problem with loading pages to the end of the web browser (probably because for them is much JavaScript)

So I added another browser to the project (Awesomium) and I question whether it is in Awesomium use `getElementById` and other...(eg: InvokeScript)?

```
var links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
{
    if (link.GetAttribute("data-bb-handler") == "ok")
    {
        link.InvokeMember("Click");
    }
}
```

Or by class name:

```
var links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
{
    if (link.GetAttribute("className") == "close")
    {
        link.InvokeMember("Click");
    }
}

webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("redeem_avatar");

HtmlElement _reward = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("name-reward");
_reward.InvokeMember("Click");
```

If you can't be in Awesomium can any other?(Gecko or something?)

Any help in advance thanks :)

Comment: In the future, please paste your code directly into the question.  I have done this for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Awesomium hasn't been updated anymore in a long time and the API reference is offline. However, you can still find it using archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20121101103943/http://awesomium.com/docs/1_6_4/sharp_api